# Are adjacent structure members of equal type adjacent in memory?

Tags: c, portability, pointer-arithmetic

In the language described by ISO 9899:2011 (that is, C11), with `T` being a complete data type and the declaration

```
struct { T a, b; } s;
```

can I assume that `&s.a + 1 == &s.b`? Did the situation change in between revisions of the C language?

Comment: What are you planning to do with this information? (e.g. dereferencing `&s.a + 1` causes UB even if it is equal to `&s.b`)

Comment: @MattMcNabb How is that going to be undefined behaviour?

Comment: It violates aliasing rules.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'm sorry, but how do I violate aliasing rules in this case? Both `s.a` and `s.b` have equal types thus the aliasing rules do not prohibit me from accessing one from a pointer to the other.

Comment: It doesn't violate aliasing rules. It violates the rule that you may not dereference a one-past-the-end pointer. (non-array variables behave like arrays of 1 element)

Comment: @MattMcNabb But the standard says that if you increment a pointer pointing to the last member of an array and another array begins just after than last member, a pointer to the first element of the next array is obtained (cf. §6.5.9/6).

Comment: @FUZxxl 6.5.9/6 is about comparing pointers for equality, not dereferencing them

Comment: Don't forget that C11 also has new `_Alignas(T)` and `_Alignas(const-expr)` alignment specifiers, so that could play a role as well. If you have `_Alignas(int) char a, b;`, then it'd be guaranteed that `a` and `b` would be aligned at an address that is a multiple of `sizeof(int)`, but that does not imply that `&a + 1 == &b` is true: if `sizeof(int)==4`, then `struct { _Alignas(int) char a, b; } s;` could result in `&s.a == (char *)0x100` and `&s.b == (char *)0x180`. That would technically still be a conforming implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The standard places no requirement on structure padding or lack of it, other than that there cannot be initial padding before the first member.

Each structure member must be correctly aligned for its type, of course.

Comment: Hm... that sounds possible. Now, if operating outside of the standard, can you name any platform where the aforementioned assumption does not hold?

Comment: SPARC platforms generally require `double` elements to be on 8-byte boundaries.  So a 9-byte type T in your example of `{double,char}` would cause "adjacent" elements to be 16 bytes apart.  Or on ANY platform where the type T or any element of type T has any type of alignment specified by #pragma or other means.  In short, and to repeat what the other posters have said - you can not make that assumption.

Comment: @AndrewHenle But the ABI on SPARC adds padding to each type so `sizeof (T)` would be a multiple of 16 if the alignment requirement of `T` is 16, thus my code would work.

Answer (score 0):

Not portable. All the standard guarantees is that offsets of members in a struct are strictly increasing. The toolchain is free to add any padding it likes.

Comment: So far, this is what Matt McNabb already said. Do you know any specific implementation where this assumption fails?